# Informatica cannot call siebel.s_sequence_pkg.get_next_rowid function

Tags: informatica, siebel

I am using **informatica** to extract data using a simple query:

```
SELECT  ' ' as ACTIVE_CTI_CFG_ID, siebel.s_sequence_pkg.get_next_rowid AS ACTIVE_TELESET_ID  from dual.
```

I am able to run this query using **Toad**.

`siebel.s_sequence_pkg.get_next_rowid` is a siebel `ROW_ID` function which I am calling in my SQL query. There is no syntax issue in the query because I can run this SQL on Toad. I am using same user credentials in Toad and informatica.

Unfortunately, informatica is throwing an error during run:

```
[‎5/‎5/‎2015 3:46 PM] Reddy, Kishore: 
Severity    Timestamp   Node    Thread  Message Code    Message
ERROR   5/5/2015 3:41:35 PM node01_MOCODEVINF01 READER_1_1_1    RR_4035 SQL Error [
ORA-00904: : invalid identifier

Database driver error...
Function Name : Execute
SQL Stmt : SELECT  ' ' as ACTIVE_CTI_CFG_ID,     siebel.s_sequence_pkg.get_next_rowid AS ACTIVE_TELESET_ID  from dual
Oracle Fatal Error
Database driver error...
Function Name : Execute
SQL Stmt : SELECT  ' ' as ACTIVE_CTI_CFG_ID,  siebel.s_sequence_pkg.get_next_rowid AS ACTIVE_TELESET_ID  from dual
Oracle Fatal Error].
```

I understand this is an oracle SQL error but why I can run this query in Toad but not in informatica?

Comment: What are you using to connect to the DB? Some ODBC or a native connector?

Answer (score 0):

I would first check that you are connecting to the same database as the same user in both cases.